# How to ratio 2:1 in jCrop?

Tags: javascript, css, jcrop

jCrop ratio is limited?
If width 2px, height 2px.
I want to aspect ratio 2:1.
How can I edit jCrop?

Comment: Following are the options provided by JCrop: http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Manual.html#Setting_Options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by `setOption` method

```
jcrop_api.setOptions(
{
    aspectRatio: 2/1
});
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I haven't read all javascript. I'll try it.